# press on the notification and open an activity where the full notification is shown

Tags: android

i m using parse push notification...i m getting notification from parse but   Since the message was not fully displayed on android, I decided to press on the notification and open an activity where the full notification is shown. We must get the "alert" and "title" from JSON and place each one of them in a TextView, but I do not know how to get the text from JSON. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which JSon ? do you have a url to get data from ?

Answer (score 0):

public class Notification extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notificationr);

TextView notification_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notification_title);
Button main= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_bckMain);
        main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(Notification.this,Home.class);
            startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button home =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_bckHome);
        home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(Notification.this,Main.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });



    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
    Log.v("Responce from JSON", jsonData);

    try{

        JSONObject notification = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String alert= notification.getString("alert");
        Log.v("alert", alert);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), alert, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        notification_title.setText(alert);


    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong with the notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}